# In Angular, is there a way to communicate imperatively to a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

#### What I know

I have a custom directive with isolate scope.
From the "outside", I can communicate **to the directive** using declarative bindings (via `@` and `=` bindings).
The directive can communicate **to the outside** using either declarative bindings (`=`) or imperative callbacks (`&`).

#### What I'd like to know

Is there any **imperative** way to communicate **to the directive**?

#### Example

Say I have a `<edit-profile>` directive.  I'd like to expose a method `reset()`, so that the owner of the directive can reset the directive (imperatively).

Here's what I'd like to do with it:

```
<edit-profile on-save="..."></edit-profile>
<button ng-click="editProfile.reset()"> Reset </button>
```

And here's my directive:

```
app.directive("editProfile", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            onSave: "&"
        },
        template: `
            <input type="text">
            <button ng-click="onSave()"> Submit </button>
        `,
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.reset = function(){ ... };
        }
    };
});
```

What ways can I achieve this kind of "imperative" approach to directive communication?

Comment: You could expose the controller of the directive to the scope, and provide functions in the controller, just like the form directive does.

Comment: Is it intended not to include the reset button to the template of the directive?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, that sounds like a great approach.  Can you elaborate on that, or perhaps add an answer with an example or a sample of the form directive?

Comment: @hgoebl Yes, the Reset button is outside the directive, simply to illustrate the intent. It's not the best example, but it's a simplification of the real use-case.

Comment: @ScottRippey I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same technique as the one used by the 'form' directive: expose the controller of the directive into its parent scope. Here's a basic example:

```
angular.module('directives').directive('foo', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            name: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.sayHello = function() {
                $scope.hello = 'hello';
            };
            $scope.name = this;
        },
        template: '<div>{{ hello }}</div>'
    };
});
```

And its unit test, showing how a link outside of the directive can call a function on the directive controller when clicked:

```
describe('foo', function() {
    var elm, scope;

    beforeEach(module('directives'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        elm = angular.element(
            '<div><foo name="bar"></foo><a href="" ng-click="bar.sayHello()">say hello</a></div>');

        scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(elm)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should say hello', function() {
        var a = elm.find('a');
        var div = elm.find('foo');

        expect(div.text()).not.toContain('hello');

        a.triggerHandler('click');

        expect(div.text()).toContain('hello');

    });
});
```

Comment: Very interesting pattern. But I don't understand how the `bar` reference gets into the outer scope. I'd have expected something like `$scope.$parent[$scope.name] = this` instead of just `$scope.name = this`. Could you please explain what happens here and how it works?

Comment: By using '=' to pass the name from the outside scope to the directive isolated scope, you're allowing the directive to assign a value to that variable and have it also referenced by the outer scope. It's two-way bound.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for! And with this, I can choose to expose the whole controller, or just an object with a subset of methods.

Comment: You expose what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge your parent scope will not know about any child scope APIs unless you start walking down the scope hierarchy.  But you can use events to do what you want.  You can use a parent scope to broadcast *down* the scope hierarchy.  It does require that your child/directive's scope *listen* for the event.

```
parentScope.$broadcast('eventName', arg1, arg2, arg3)

directiveScope.$on('eventName', function(event, arg1, arg2, arg3){ })
```

I would recommend that you stop the event from further propagation.

Check out these links:

- [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)
- https://jwopitz.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/notes-on-angular-2014-06-10/

Comment: Ok, that sounds like an interesting way to communicate "down".  It does have some drawbacks, like, if there were two directives, I couldn't broadcast to just one of them.  But I'll take this into consideration.

Comment: Yes it does have drawbacks.  If you were talking about multiple directive instances under a parent scope, you would probably send in the `$index` (if using a repeater) or a name/id as part of the event payload.  Then whichever directive scope processes the event as the intended target could call `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` so that sibling scopes don't process it.